# How can you ignore a field during serialization but not during deserialization?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have a POJO class

```
class Human{
    String name;
    Integer age;
    //get and set
}
```

When I deserialize json to a `Human` object I want to read both fields (`age` and `name` values). But when I serialize a `Human` object to json I want to ignore `age`.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The javadoc of [`@JsonIgnore`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) states

> In addition, starting with Jackson 1.9, if this is the only annotation
>   associated with a property, it will also cause cause the whole
>   property to be ignored: that is, if setter has this annotation and
>   getter has no annotations, getter is also effectively ignored. **It is
>   still possible for different accessors to use different annotations;
>   so if only "getter" is to be ignored, other accessors (setter or
>   field) would need explicit annotation to prevent ignoral (usually
>   JsonProperty).**

So just annotate the getter and setter appropriately

```
// for serialization
@JsonIgnore 
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
// for deserialization
@JsonProperty("name")
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```